# grep-ing a variable vs. a file - execution time

Tags: bash, curl, grep

made an interesting observation - I was storing the output of a cURL statement in a text file and then grep-ing it for certain strings. Later I changed my code to store the output to a variable instead. Turns out, this change caused my script to run much slower. This was really counter intuitive for me since I always thought I/O operations would be more expensive than in-memory operations. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="http://m.cnbc.com"
while read line; do
  UA=$line
  curl -s --location --user-agent "$UA" $URL > RAW.txt
  #RAW=`curl --location --user-agent "$UA" $URL`
  L=`grep -c -e "Advertise With Us" RAW.txt`
  #L=`echo $RAW | grep -c -e "Advertise With Us"`
  M=`grep -c -e "id='menu'><button>Menu</button>" RAW.txt`
  #M=`echo $RAW | grep -c -e "id='menu'><button>Menu</button>"`
  D=`grep -c -e "Careers" RAW.txt`
  #D=`echo $RAW | grep -c -e "Careers"`
  if [[ ( $L == 1 && $M == 0 ) && ( $D == 0) ]]
    then
      AC="Legacy"
  elif [[ ( $L == 0 && $M == 1 ) && ( $D == 0) ]]
    then
  AC="Modern"
  elif [[ ( $L == 0 && $M == 0 ) && ( $D == 1) ]]
    then
      AC="Desktop"
  else
  AC="Unable to Determine"
  fi
  echo $AC >> Results.txt
done < UserAgents.txt
```

The commented lines represent the storing-in-variable approach. Any ideas why would this be happening? Also are there any ways to further speed-up this script? Right now it takes about 8 minutes to process 2000 input entries.

Comment: In your original version, `RAW.txt` probably fit into cache, so you weren't paying an I/O penalty for successive calls to `grep` on it. In your "optimized" version, you are increasing the number of processes you need to fork due to the pipelines that feeds each call to `grep`. Keep in mind, though, that if you want speed, forking several processes for each of the 2000 lines is the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Chepner is correct. Read each call to `cURL` just once, flagging each of the three desired strings. Here's some example code using `awk`. Completely untested:

```
URL="http://m.cnbc.com"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    RAW=$(curl --location --user-agent "$line" $URL)

    awk '
    /Advertise With Us/ {
        L=1
    }
    /id='\''menu'\''><button>Menu<\/button>/ {
        M=1
    }
    /Careers/ {
        D=1
    }

    END {
        if (L==1 && M==0 && D==0) {
            s = "Legacy"
        }
        else if (L==0 && M==1 && D==0) {
            s = "Modern"
        }
        else if (L==0 && M==0 && D==1) {
            s = "Desktop"
        }
        else {
            s = "Unable to Determine"
        }

        print s >> "Results.txt"
    }' "$RAW"

done < UserAgents.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to count the number of matches with `grep -c`? It looks like you just need to know if a match was found or not. If so, you can simply use bash's in-built string comparison.

Also, it will be faster if you write to the results file outside the loop.

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="http://m.cnbc.com"
while read line
do
  UA="$line"
  RAW=$(curl -s --location --user-agent "$UA" "$URL")
  [[ $RAW == *"Advertise With Us"* ]] && L=1 || L=0
  [[ $RAW == *"id='menu'><button>Menu</button>"* ]] && M=1 || M=0
  [[ $RAW == *Careers* ]] && D=1 || D=0

  if (( L==1 && M==0 && D==0 ))
  then
     AC="Legacy"
  elif (( L==1 && M==1 && D==0 ))
  then
     AC="Modern"
  elif (( L==1 && M==0 && D==1 ))
  then
     AC="Desktop"
  else
     AC="Unable to Determine"
  fi
  echo "$AC" 
done < UserAgents.txt > Results.txt
```

Comment: @dogbaneDo you really need to count the number of matches with grep -c? It looks like you just need to know if a match was found or not.